# libpam load pam modules at every connection

Tags: linux, pam, sshd

I want to reduce ssh connection time, by debugging sshd have found that libpam is loading all pam modules specified in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file at every connection.

How to configure/modifiy libpam such that it loads modules only for first connection and after it uses same modules for every connection? I know libpam was designed for loading pam modules but want to load pam modules once.

Let me know if anyone have any idea.

I'm using `OpenSSH_5.8p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0l and Linux-PAM-1.1.3`

Comment: My gut tells me that the way SSHD does privilege separation could affect how often modules get reloaded.  There are extra processes involved with certain PrivSep levels.    If I were testing this my self, I would turn UsePrivilegeSeparation to NO and then restart sshd, and check if that had any effect.